# App runs on Visual studio but not directly running exe, why?

Tags: deployment

This piece of code works fine on Visual Studio 2010 (debug/release) perfectly with return value from the dll function (ctrl+F5 gets output).

Now issue is, when i run this exe directly from debug folder, it is not returning the value.

What is the problem.

```
typedef int (*One)(const char *);
HMODULE hModule;
One gpfSN = NULL;
int y = 0;
const char *cr = "xyz";
        hModule = LoadLibrary(L"send.dll");
    if (hModule != NULL)    
    {
        gpfSN = (One)GetProcAddress(hModule, "GetData");
    }

    if (gpfSN != NULL) 
    {
        CString t;
        y = (*gpfSN)(cr);
        t.Format(_T("%d"), y);
        m_Value.SetWindowTextW(t);
    }
    if (hModule != NULL) 
    {
    ::FreeLibrary(hModule);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add some error reporting because right now all the errors are silently ignored.

```c++
if (hModule != NULL)    
{
    gpfSN = (One)GetProcAddress(hModule, "GetData");
}
else
{
    auto const last_error(::GetLastError());
    m_Value.SetWindowTextW(L"LoadLibrary call failed"); // TODO print error code
}
```

Comment: Displays "LoadLibrary call failed" Not loading library? Same path worked on Visual studio, path problem?

Comment: You should inspect error code. And do you even have send.dll there?

Comment: After setting dll path in system variable, It worked from debug folder. But Now, when copy the exe to another folder, same old problem should be 126 code error

Comment: Are your exe and L"send.dll" located in the same folder?

Comment: I think both should not be in same folder.

Comment: If they are not in the same folder then you should consider configuring [dll search order](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682586(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: Thank you @dodo951